# How to convert Jquery method to React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, charts

I am using react component for chart resize the method that I used in jquery fiddle need to covert to react

[Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/2/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/members/chart-setsize/)

I am using `react-grid-layout` component which I am rendering high chart and d3 charts after resize the chart is not getting resized. In query the same functionality is working absolutely fine so i need to convert the same in react

Comment: Use react version of High Chart instead . https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts

Comment: i am using the same reac-highcharts i am able to create chart the problem is with resizable on resize chart is not getting resized on layout change i am using react-grid-layout component